# Why the form onsubmit validation is not iterating through all possibilities?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, onsubmit

First time posting here, last alternative to getting even more frustrated with this non-sense. I see nothing wrong with this code segment and yet the onsubmit condition seems to be always returning as true, even if I leave the fields blank (which should be verified on the spot).

NOTE: my JS functions are blank at the moment, haven't gotten that far yet.

Further investigation note: even the final case which I wrote to be a catch all is not working, it's simply trying to reach the checkout page as soon as I hit submit and completely ignoring the onsubmit.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> Book registration. </title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = 'Script/main.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method = "POST" action = "Checkout" onsubmit = "validate(this)">      
        <fieldset>
        <legend> Book Registry Access </legend>

        <p> ISBN: <input type = "text" size = "14" name = "ISBN" onchange = "if(this.value != '') ajaxVerif('checkISBN', this.value, this.id);"> </p>
        <p> Title: <input type = "text" size = "32" id = "title" name = "title"> </p>
        <p> Author: <input type = "text" size = "32" id = "author" name = "author"> </p>
        <p> Edition: <input type = "text" size = "2" id = "edition" name = "edition" onchange = "if(this.value != '') ajaxVerif('checkEdi', this.value, this.id);"> </p>
        <p> <input type = "submit"> </p>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

    function validate(thisForm)
    {
    if (thisForm.ISBN.value == '') {
                    alert('Please enter a valid ISBN number in the form XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ');
                    this.ISBN.focus();
                    return false;
                }
    if (thisForm.title.value == '') {
                    alert('Please fill in the title field.');
                    this.title.focus();
                    return false;
                }   
    if (thisForm.author.value == '') {
                    alert('Please fill in the author field.');
                    this.author.focus();
                    return false;
                }
    if (thisForm.edition.value == '') {
                    alert('Please enter a valid edition number.');
                    this.edition.focus();
                    return false;
                }
    alert('Success! This test form is working! (TO BE DELETED!!)');
    return false;
    }
```

EDIT: edited for cleanliness, still cannot get it to work. So now everything works in terms of verification except, apparently, the returning false. It will always try to jump to the next page (and fail because that links to a dummy page). I am not quite sure why, pretty sure all my returns should be ok.

FINAL EDIT: Fixed, I forgot to write it as onsubmit = 'return validate(this)'>

Comment: Please don't inline JavaScript as you would inline PHP. It's plainly wrong and painful to the eyes

Comment: I agree with Alexender, that inline javascript makes me cringe.

Comment: You're missing a `}` before `if (this.author.value == '') {`

Comment: Sorry about the inlining, I hadn

Comment: Wow, enter fail. Anyways, I hadn't written the JS file yet, so I will be fixing that. Just wanted to say thanks, you guys are a lifesaver, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Spoke too soon, now only the first one (ISBN) is validating. And yet they're all written the same way. It's still doing the same thing where the final condition is not even being evaluated it's just jumping to the next page if the first condition checks out.

Comment: You also forgot to keep replacing replacing `this` with `thisForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, avoid inline JavaScript.

You would have noticed the missing `}` by keeping a clean JavaScript code.

```
  if (this.title.value == '') {
    alert('Please fill in the title field.');
    this.title.focus();
    return false;
  }
--^--
```

---

### UPDATE

1. You forgot the  `return`, and

   ```
   onsubmit = "return validate(this);"
            ---^^^^^^---         ---^---
   ```
2. You also forgot to finish replacing `this` with `thisForm`.

Comment: Thanks again, man, I really appreciate it. Would you have any idea what could cause the following: when I add this line :

<script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxVerif.js"></script>

To the start of my JS file, it causes the JS contained in the file to stop working. Any ideas? The whole point is I'm incluiding that with the end goal of writing a function that calls my ajax to access my XML

Comment: @GregoryFischer-Rush, nope. No one could answer that without some context. For instance, a syntax error as already happened to you. You may want to create a new question for it